# Deleting Redux Data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a list data that I displayed to a table. I also have a `View` component which I pass the specific data of a list. My problem is when I try to delete something on the `View` modal dialog. I can't make the the redux data delete reducer work.

I saw in my redux devtools that its deleting state in cards array. BUT not shown updated result in Modal Dialog.

I guess because of passing it to Modal. Thats my problem.

pls check my codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-react-zs4fu?file=/src/Reducers/personReducer.js)

```
case personConstants.DELETE_CARD_SUCCESS:
  const { id, card_id } = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    persons: state.persons.map((value) =>
      value.id === id
        ? {
            ...value,
            cards: value.cards.filter((item) => item.id !== card_id)
          }
        : value
    )
  };
```

Comment: can you check if `value.id === id` is true or not? Is `value.id` and `id` of same type?

Comment: @gmoniava. I think thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to persons change with useEffect in App.js and then you can decide what to do with updating data. For example, you can do something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedDetails(null);
  }, [persons]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the reducer updates the application state, `selectedDetails` in App.js won't change because it only updates when you click the open button. I would recommend connecting your modal directly to the redux state so when it changes it will update the view.